# Dynamic data type like id?

Tags: java, android, ios

I am developing an application on both iOS and Android. I want to check what is the equivalent data type similar to Objective-C's "id" in Java (android), like how 'id' supports dynamic binding and typing.

Could someone guide me, since i could't find answer for this yet?

Comment: as far as I know, you get something equivalent in java by using reflection on `Object`s (and it does not get more convenient than this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no duck typing in Java, so one cannot call arbitrary method of arbitrary object in Java, hence there's no such magic type like `id`.

One must explicitly cast to desired type and only then call desired method.

However there's `invokedynamic` introduced in Java 7, but I'm not sure you can use it directly in Java code right now.

I'll advise to analyze cases where you need that duck typing `id` magic and think how to avoid it.